# Gerar template de arquivo com Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, template

Bom dia pessoal.

Com o Maven Archetype é possível gerar templates de projetos.

Existe alguma forma de gerar templates de arquivo para Netbeans com Maven?

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

olha eu tenho 4 links que podem ajudar nesta sua questão:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-modulesingle.html

http://www.taringamberini.com/en/blog/howto/java/how-to-create-a-maven-archetype-in-netbeans/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_netbeans.htm

Aconselho fortemente o primeiro link. :)

Comment: É interessante você montar um exemplo, mesmo que básico, explicando como fazer. Se você passar só os links de outros sites, estes podem não estar disponíveis no futuro.

Comment: Olá Deivison. Acho que você não entendeu a minha pergunta. Eu quero criar um modelo de arquivo, por exemplo, um teste de controller para que sempre que eu precisar criar um teste eu vou lá e crio usando este modelo. O Maven Archetype cria template de projetos, o que preciso é criar template de arquivo.